# How to save multiple array input data in Database in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-7

Hello Geeks i am stuck here. I am beginner and want to know how to save and update array data in database.
[this is laravel form requested data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSD6K.png)

I want to save data like this :
[mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEr4I.png)

here is my form request, i want to save data in mysql database, with new row :

````
"_token" => "FoyoYvFXmNAggbQuMq6PN243QS43MkY99Nq3UAni"
"description" => array:2 [▼
 0 => "<h3>Shared Hosting Plan</h3>"
 1 => "<h3>Cloud Hosting Plan</h3>"
]
"site_id" => array:2 [▼
 0 => "5361"
 1 => "5361"
]
"category_id" => array:2 [▼
 0 => "1"
 1 => "3"
]
"field_1" => array:2 [▶]
"field_2" => array:2 [▶]
"field_3" => array:2 [▶]
"field_4" => array:2 [▶]
"field_5" => array:1 [▶]
"price" => array:2 [▶]
"update_plan" => "Save Plans"
]```
````

Comment: If you have the control to formulate the Request, I would suggest you to send the request as properly formatted request.

Comment: ```php
[
  ['description' => '<h3>Shared Hosting Plan</h3>', 'site_id' => '5361', 'category_id' => '1'],
  ['description' => '<h3>Cloud Hosting Plan</h3>', 'site_id' => '5361', 'category_id' => '3']
]
```
If you can send the request as above, you can deal with it easily in the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this**

```
    $save_data=[];
    foreach($data['description'] as $key=>$desc){
        $save_data[]=[
            'description'=>$desc,
            'site_id'=>$data['site_id'][$key],
            'category_id'=>$data['category_id'][$key],
            'feature_field_1'=>$data['field_1'][$key],
            'feature_field_2'=>$data['field_2'][$key],
            'feature_field_3'=>$data['field_3'][$key],
            'feature_field_4'=>$data['field_4'][$key],
            'feature_field_5'=>$data['field_5'][$key],
            'price'=>$data['price'][$key]
        ]
    }
    \DB::table('table')->insert($save_data);
```

Comment: You should group data and insert multi records  : `$save_data[] = [...]` and move `\DB::table('table')->insert($save_data);` out `foreach`

Comment: at a time only 1 record insert

Comment: you can check document of insert laravel : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#insert-statements

Comment: `You may insert several records at once by passing an array of arrays.`

Answer (score 0):

You can insert like this

**Eloquent approach**

```
Model::insert($data);
```

**Query Builder approach**

```
DB::table('table')->insert($data);
```